# React-Leaflet shows TS2769: No overload matches this call. TypeError

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I've made a mapping component using `react-leaflet` and it works really well, however I can only get it to build if I add the `@ts-ignore` lines in the example below. If I do not I get an error saying:

> `TS2769: No overload matches this call.`

If I output the value of `postition` I get `[13.298034302, 43.0488191271]` and `imageBounds` gives me `[{lat: 14.194809302, lng: 42.3558566271}, {lat: 12.401259302, lng: 43.7417816271}]` (I've also tried this as an array of values without the object with the same result.

I can't see where I'm going wrong and I'd rather not publish code with the @ts-ignore in it if I can help it.

Here is the code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet'

/* Import Types */
import PropTypes from './types/props'

/* Import Stylesheet */
import './leaflet.css'
import styles from './styles.module.scss'

const defaultProps: PropTypes = {
  bounds: {
    imageTop: 0,
    imageLeft: 0,
    imageRight: 0,
    imageBottom: 0
  },
  tileLayer: {
    url: '',
    attribution: ''
  },
  minZoom: 8,
  maxZoom: 12,
  touchZoom: true,
  zoom: 10,
  zoomDelta: 0.25,
  zoomSnap: 0.25,
  zoomControl: true,
  attributionControl: false,
  zoomAnimation: false
}

/* Render component */
export const Mapping: React.FunctionComponent<PropTypes> = ({
  bounds,
  tileLayer,
  minZoom,
  maxZoom,
  touchZoom,
  zoom,
  zoomDelta,
  zoomSnap,
  zoomControl,
  attributionControl,
  zoomAnimation
}: PropTypes) => {
  const { imageTop, imageLeft, imageRight, imageBottom } = bounds
  const position = [(imageTop + imageBottom) / 2, (imageLeft + imageRight) / 2]
  const imageBounds = [{ lat: imageTop, lng: imageLeft }, { lat: imageBottom, lng: imageRight }]

  return (
    <Map
      // @ts-ignore
      bounds={imageBounds}
      className={styles['map-container']}
      zoom={zoom}
      zoomDelta={zoomDelta}
      zoomSnap={zoomSnap}
      minZoom={minZoom}
      zoomControl={zoomControl}
      maxZoom={maxZoom}
      touchZoom={touchZoom}
      zoomAnimation={zoomAnimation}
      attributionControl={attributionControl}
    >
      <TileLayer
        url={tileLayer.url}
        attribution={tileLayer.attribution}

      />

      <Marker
        // @ts-ignore
        position={position}>
        <Popup>A pretty CSS3 popup.<br />Easily customizable.</Popup>
      </Marker>
    </Map>
  )
}
Mapping.defaultProps = defaultProps

export default Mapping
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly declare the proptypes using an interface since you are using typescript like this:

```
interface IMapping {
  bounds?: [number, number][] | LatLngBounds | undefined;
  tileLayer?: {
    url: string;
    attribution: string;
  };
  zoom?: number;
  minZoom?: number;
  maxZoom?: number;
  touchZoom?: boolean;
  zoomDelta?: number;
  zoomSnap?: number;
  zoomControl?: boolean;
  attributionControl?: boolean;
  zoomAnimation?: boolean;
}
```

All these are required to be passed as props when including `Mapping` component. 
In the example I use `?` which makes the props non required for the sake of the example. If you do not include `?` which makes a prop optional you will get the following error:

> “Type '{}' is missing in the following properties…”

Then use it like this:

```
const Mapping: React.FC<IMapping> = ....
```

Same for `position`, `imageBounds` variables etc...:

```
const position: [number, number] = [13.298034302, 43.0488191271];
```

you need to declare the type of the variable.

Here is [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-shows-ts2769-no-overload-matches-this-call-typerror-8744i) with most of your code included with types to help you get started with types declaration to your project.

Comment: Thank you, it was this that I was missing:

```const position: [number, number] = [(imageTop + imageBottom) / 2, (imageLeft + imageRight) / 2]
  const imageBounds: [[number, number], [number, number]] = [[imageTop, imageLeft], [imageBottom, imageRight]]
```

Pretty new to TypeScript, there seem to be a lot of 'gotchas'!